# postfix new mail notifications

Tags: php, postfix

We're looking at embedding a Postfix mail setup into an existing web (php  / mysql) product so that it can offer inbuilt email send/recieve support along with mail account management (its a CRM).

Ideally I don't want to be polling via POP3 or IMAP every so often to see if an account has new mail - is there a way to configure postfix so that it runs a script every time it receives a new mail?

That way, as long as it includes details of the recipient, I could setup a notification for the user within the CRM and not have to constantly poll the mail accounts.

Comment: Would it help you to use IMAP IDLE to keep an eye on things? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMAP_IDLE

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/536648/postfix-pass-a-copy-of-an-email-to-a-script-but-deliver-the-original-one-to-mai

Comment: You could use incron to monitor the mail directories and execute scripts.